# Java + Groovy Script - Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, groovy, groovyshell

I have a problem with inheritance in Groovy script. I want my Groovy script to inherit methods from Java class that I invoke this script.

For example, I have something like this:

```
public class SimpleTest extends TestCase {

public void test(){
    CompilerConfiguration configuration = new CompilerConfiguration();
    configuration.setScriptBaseClass(this.getClass().getName());
    GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), new Binding(), configuration);
    shell.evaluate("println sayHello()");
}

public String sayHello(){
    return "Hello";
}
}
```

And the error is:

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
>   Script1.groovy: 1: Declared type com.test.SimpleTest does not extend groovy.lang.Script class!
>    @ line 1, column 1.
>      println sayHello()
>      ^                                                                                    1 error

How can I do this if I cannot inherit any other class? I want to invoke method just only like from superclass.

**Edit**

I changed my class to something like this:

```
public class CmTest extends TestCase {

public void test(){
    GroovyHandler handler = new GroovyHandler();
    handler.run();
}

public String sayHello(){
    return "Hello";
}

public class GroovyHandler extends Script {

    public GroovyHandler(){
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        CompilerConfiguration configuration = new CompilerConfiguration();
        configuration.setScriptBaseClass(this.getClass().getName());
        GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(CmTest.class.getClassLoader(), new Binding(), configuration);
        return shell.evaluate("println sayHello()");
    }
}
}
```

Now the error is:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.test.SimpleTest$GroovyHandler: method < init >()V not found
>       at Script1.(Script1.groovy)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.createScript(InvokerHelper.java:429)
>       at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:704)
>       at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:588)
>       at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:627)
>       at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:598) ...

Answer (score 0):

The class that is going to be used in the script must extend [Script](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/lang/Script.html)

Example:

```
class ScriptTest extends Script {
    def SayHello() {
        return "Hello"
    }
}
```

Then you `setScriptBaseClass` to this particular class

Comment: since the above is imho the answer to the original question I just add here: `com.test.SimpleTest$GroovyHandler` indicates, that your script base class is an inner class and I assume it is not a static inner class. Java will not add a parameterless constructor in that case, since the inner class needs to take the outer class instance. So simply make the class static and all is fine

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. The solution is class DelegatingScript.
Link to doc:
http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/DelegatingScript.html